# How to retrieve "name" value from json using bash?

Tags: bash, curl, grep, sh, jq

I am using the following curl command:

```
curl -s  -v --user admin:orca --insecure -X GET https://insecure.registry.com/api/v0/repositories/authi-api/tags
```

Getting following output:

```
   {
    "name": "Dev_ReleaseRollout_Lane-3",
    "inRegistry": true,
    "hashMismatch": false,
    "inNotary": false
   },
   {
    "name": "Dev_ReleaseRollout_Lane-latest",
    "inRegistry": true,
    "hashMismatch": false,
    "inNotary": false
   },
   {
    "name": "Payments_Dev_Lane-267",
    "inRegistry": true,
    "hashMismatch": false,
    "inNotary": false
   }
```

I want to get only `name` values in a variable.
I need only `Dev_ReleaseRollout_Lane-3` `Dev_ReleaseRollout_Lane-latest` `Payments_Dev_Lane-267` in a variable

Comment: Which commands have you tried so far, and what did they output?

Comment: Do you get an array: `[...]` or the output mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you actually have an array around the three objects:

```
$ curl ... | jq -r '.[].name'
Dev_ReleaseRollout_Lane-3
Dev_ReleaseRollout_Lane-latest
Payments_Dev_Lane-267
```

It's fairly simple, `.` is the array, `[].name` take name from each element in the array. `-r` is raw output.

> `--raw-output / -r:`
>   With this option, if the filter’s result is a string then it will be written directly to standard output rather than being formatted as a JSON string with quotes. This can be useful for making jq filters talk to non-JSON-based systems.

If the cURL output is actually as mentioned above the following will work:

```
jq -rRs '"[\(.)]" | fromjson[].name' file.json
```

However I think there is a better way to wrap an array around input,

`-R` is raw input and `-s` is slurp. `\(...)` is [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo)).

> `--slurp/-s:`
>   Instead of running the filter for each JSON object in the input, read the entire input stream into a large array and run the filter just once.